# How to create a mock interface for an object inheriting multiple interfaces

Tags: c#, mocking, tdd

I am the customer of a library generating objects of class `C` which implements two interfaces `IA` and `IB`, which represents a permanent connection which I need to store.

I need to store the object `C` returned between calls.

```
class Example
{
    C   _obj;
}
```

I would like to mock the interface functions used by `C` for testing, but because 'C' inherits multiple interface I do not have an interface `IC`, so I cannot write:

```
class Example
{
    Example(IC cInstance) { _obj = cInstance; }
    IC  _obj;
}
```

therefore I cannot create easily a mock object that would implement both interfaces `IA` and `IB` which I could use for testing that my class `Example` works.

How do I do this without using casting or something ugly ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it using generics:

```
class Example<T> where T : IA, IB
{
    public Example(T instance)
    {
        this.obj = instance;
    }
    private T obj;
}
```

You can use `C` or your mockup with `Example` as long as that class implements both interfaces:

```
class CMock : IA, IB
{
    // ...
}

var myMockObj = new CMock();
var example = new Example<CMock>(myMockObj);
```

Comment: I keep this solution in my side pocket.

Answer (score 3):

If the object inherits two interfaces, probably should you store two references:

```
class Example
{
    Example(IA aInstance, IB bInstance) { _a = aInstance; _b = bInstance; }
    IA  _a;
    IB  _b;
}
```

And that's not ugly. On the contrary.

Comment: I really like your solution, I would have done it whenever I have to write C++ code, however I accepted the other answer in the end.

Comment: This is a good alternative solution since it can handle the case where two different classes implement IA and IB.